# Проект с разными кодировками.

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка

Достался проект с кучей комментариев на русском и в разных кодировках(windiws-1251,koi8-r,utf-8). Конечно netbeans поддерживает вся эти кодировки, на постоянно переключать их в свойствах проекта очень мутерно. Может кто-нибудь подсказать адекватный способ привести комментариев кодировки к одному виду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм такой, все файлы построчно считать и определять для каждой строки кодировку и приводить если надо к нужной.

Ссылки:

[habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107945/)

[dklab](http://forum.dklab.ru/viewtopic.php?t=37830)

Comment: Статьи реально помогли проникнуть в суть проблемы. Жалко что готового решения нет. Лан пойду делать.